# AutoMapper Multi-level Child Inheritance not working anymore in 12.0.1 after upgrading from 12.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper-12

It's best to demonstrate this issue with a fiddle. The following fiddle is using AutoMapper 12.0.1 and will fail the test.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qtvc1Z

The following is the same codes but using AutoMapper 12.0.0 which works judging from the absence of exception.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yki6GC

The child has 3 levels of inheritance with the `Parent` property should have been ignored in   the mapping of the base classes. However it seems like it wasn't in the derived classes.

I'm including the codes below for completeness.

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using AutoMapper;

#region Child

public class ChildSourceBase
{
}

public class ChildDestinationBase
{
    public ParentDestination Parent { get; set; } = null!;
}


public class ChildSourceMiddle : ChildSourceBase
{
}

public class ChildDestinationDerived: ChildDestinationBase
{
}


public class ChildSourceDerived : ChildSourceMiddle
{
}

#endregion

#region Parent

public class ParentSourceBase
{
}

public class ParentDestination
{
    public ChildDestinationBase Child { get; set; } = null!;
}


public class ParentSourceDerived : ParentSourceBase
{
    public ChildSourceDerived Child { get; set; } = null!;
}

#endregion

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            #region Parent
                
            cfg.CreateMap<ParentSourceBase, ParentDestination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Child, opt => opt.Ignore());
            
            cfg.CreateMap<ParentSourceDerived, ParentDestination>()
                .IncludeBase<ParentSourceBase, ParentDestination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Child, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child))
                ;
            
            #endregion
            
            #region Child
                
            cfg.CreateMap<ChildSourceBase, ChildDestinationBase>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Parent, opt => opt.Ignore()); // `Parent` property should've been ignored here.
            
            cfg.CreateMap<ChildSourceMiddle, ChildDestinationDerived>()
                .IncludeBase<ChildSourceBase, ChildDestinationBase>();
            
            cfg.CreateMap<ChildSourceDerived, ChildDestinationDerived>() // however, here is complaining that `Parent` property is not mapped.
                .IncludeBase<ChildSourceMiddle, ChildDestinationDerived>();
            
            #endregion
        });     
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

This happens only to the child (nested object). If there's no nesting involved, multi-level inheritance doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build. This is already solved.
See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4213.